# Reinicio de array en Javascript

Tags: array, tabla-dinámica, paginacion

Hola que tal amigos buenas tardes, verán estoy haciendo una tabla con dos columnas principales(Nombre del producto y Lotes), en la columna *Lotes* el usuario digita en las cajas de texto la cantidad de lotes por producto que requiere, hasta ahí funciona bien pero como mi tabla contiene más de 100 registros decidí aplicar el paginate y ahora se reinicia el array.
Ejemplo:
Si el usuario quiere 3 lotes de X producto que esta en la página 1, y 2 lotes de otro producto que está en la página dos, al momento de hacer cambio de la página 1 a la 2 olvida los que digitó en la página 1 y solo muestra los de la 2.
Lo ideal sería que vaya almacenando el array sin importar en que página de la tabla esté el usuario.

AQUI LES DEJO MI CÓDIGO, estoy usando **Laravel** en conjunto con **Javascript** para este formulario.

```
**MI TABLA**

   <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>Nombre</th>
                      <th>Lote</th>
                      <th>OSTHM</th>
                      <th>FTHM</th>
                      <th>DTHM</th>
                      <th>CFTHM</th>
                      <th>DLTHM</th>
                      <th>LBTHM</th>
                      <th>NTHM</th>
                      <th>RMTHM</th>
                      <th>E1THM</th>
                      <th>E2THM</th>
                      <th>LTHM</th>
                      <th>C2THM</th>
                      <th>C3THM</th>
                      <th>EKTHM</th>
                      <th>M1THM</th>
                      <th>M2THM</th>
                      <th>CA1THM</th>
                      <th>CA2THM</th>
                      <th>EFTHM</th>

                      

                     </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody name="listaElementos" id="listaElementos">
                      @foreach($ruta as $r)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$r->idr}}</td>
                        <td name="nombre" id="nombre">{{$r->productos->nombre}}</td>
                        <td><input class='form-control' type="number" id="txt-cant"></td>
                        <td name="OSTHM" id="OSTHM">{{$r->OSTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="FTHM" id="FTHM">{{$r->FTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="DTHM" id="DTHM">{{$r->DTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="CFTHM" id="CFTHM">{{$r->CFTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="DLTHM" id="DLTHM">{{$r->DLTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="LBTHM" id="LBTHM">{{$r->LBTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="NTHM" id="NTHM">{{$r->NTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="RMTHM" id="RMTHM">{{$r->RMTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="E1THM" id="E1THM">{{$r->E1THM}}</td>
                        <td name="E2THM" id="E2THM">{{$r->E2THM}}</td>
                        <td name="LTHM" id="LTHM">{{$r->LTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="C2THM" id="C2THM">{{$r->C2THM}}</td>
                        <td name="C3THM" id="C3THM">{{$r->C3THM}}</td>
                        <td name="EKTHM" id="EKTHM">{{$r->EKTHM}}</td>
                        <td name="M1THM" id="M1THM">{{$r->M1THM}}</td>
                        <td name="M2THM" id="M2THM">{{$r->M2THM}}</td>
                        <td name="CA1THM" id="CA1THM">{{$r->CA1THM}}</td>
                        <td name="CA2THM" id="CA2THM">{{$r->CA2THM}}</td>
                        <td name="EFTHM" id="EFTHM">{{$r->EFTHM}}</td>
                        
                      
                        
                           </td>

                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  
                </div>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-block bg-gradient-success" value="Análisis" id="analisis" >
```

**Mi función Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#analisis').click(function(){
        obtenerDatosTabla();
        
       
    });
    });

    
    function obtenerDatosTabla(){
      document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML = '';

    $('#listaElementos tr').each(function(){
     let codigo=$(this).find('#nombre').eq(0).text(); 
     let cantidad=$(this).find('#txt-cant').val();
     let nombre= codigo;        

     for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {  
      document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML +=
       "<td>"+nombre +"</td>"         
   
     }
    });

    
    }
       
    </script>
```

Comment: al realizar el paginado recargas la pagina? pues si este es el caso es un problema por que al recargar la página las variables vuelven a inicializarse, ahora bien para resolver esto lo que debes de hacer es que cuando cambies de pagina le mandes los datos del array al controlador y lo vuelves a retornar, tendras que estar jugando con el array para saber en que posición estaba el dato

Comment: No, no recargo la página

Comment: Solo doy "Next" o el número del paginate para ver otros datos y la variable vuelve a inicializarce, no almacena